# Windows8.1 Bluetooth Tray Icon Disappeared After Reboot

Tags: windows, bluetooth, mouse

My scenario as below :

1- First reboot of the computer, there is no Bluetooth Tray Icon and my mouse is not working. After i click "change the bluetooth settings" and i check the "Show the bluetooth icon in the notification area", still no Bluetooth icon and my mouse still not working. 
2- I restart the windows 
3- Now there is Bluetooth icon in the notification area and mouse working. 
4- Restart the windows. 
5- No bluetooth icon and mouse is not working, same as step 1.

My windows version is 8.1 and using Microsoft Sculpt Mouse. 
Also my notebook is Sony Vaio Duo 13.

Regards.

Comment: Step #4. Is that a sleep/hibernate? Maybe the Bluetooth device fails to handle resume. :-,(

Answer (score 0):

open your notification tray there you see coustomise option. click that then one window will open there at left bottom you see on opetion "Restore defalut behaviour" click that then everthy thing wil come normal